# How to access resources in one tenant from another tenant in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I have tenant-1, that has the entire infrastructure for my application web-1 (db, virtual n/w, sites etc).

I have a requirement to perform app registration for web-1 in tenant-2 & then try to access the resouces. Is this even possible?

Right now, I get 401 unauthorized error when I register the app in tenant2 and try to access the underlying resources in tenant1 from tenant2.

Do I need to make the app multi-tenant ? Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Yes app registration essentially create a service principal that you can used for RBAC. You may have missed a step to assign some roles to the registered app in tenant-2?

If your app already registered in tenant-1, you will need to create enterprise app in tenant-2 and use federation to connect them.

Update:

Add Links for App registration and Enterprise Application
https://www.nathannellans.com/post/app-registrations-enterprise-apps-and-service-principals

Multi-tenant application:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant

Application, AAD & Service Principle
https://endjin.com/blog/2019/01/managing-applications-using-azure-ad-service-principals-and-managed-identities

Comment: Thanks. Can you please elaborate or share documentation that explains how after performing app registration in tenant 2,  I can grant right roles to my service principal -- to access resources in tenant1?

Comment: Sorry I might mis-interpreted the question. The app registration in tenant-2, can only access the resources(do RBAC) in subscription-2 that trust the tenant-2. And you can have multiple subscriptions trust one AAD tenant, but each subscription can only trust one AAD tenant. So no you cannot access subscription 1 that already trust tenant-1. I hope this help. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-how-subscriptions-associated-directory

Comment: The potential solution is falling back to have a App registration in tenant-1 and have an enterprise application in tenant-2. I update the answer to add some links