# Un authorized text shown on page got redirected to my application after granting admin consent to new tenant

Tags: azure, active-directory, single-page-application, multi-tenant

I have two tenants t1 and t2. On t1 when admin of t2 logs in it asks for admin consent at this URL:

[https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/v2.0/adminconsent?client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendars.Readhttps://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.Send&redirect_uri=http://localhost/myapp/permissions](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant%7D/v2.0/adminconsent?client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendars.Readhttps://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.Send&redirect_uri=http://localhost/myapp/permissions)

Admin login is successful then permission are granted and under ENTERPRISE APPLICATION of t2 , t1 app is being created.

When user is redirected back to my application page on below URL its says Unauthorized!!!

http://localhost/myapp/permissions?admin_consent=True&tenant=fa00d692-e9c7-4460-a743-29f2956fd429&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendars.Read https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.Send

If I remove scopes from this Url then it hits my single page without un authorized error and works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***We have tried the same ,to achieve it on our end and it works***.

*We have created 2 tenant from our admin site* .

[image]

***Created Enterprise application with register an application under Tenant-A with providing below permissions for that application for users and Grant Admin for consent as well***.

[image]

[image]

*Now, need to configure with Tenant-B , So to give scope and access to other tenant or to [**`add guest user and send an invitation`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/b2b-quickstart-add-guest-users-portal) so that it can be accessible we can send the invitation and accept by using the admin credentials of other tenant as mentioned in the given MS DOC . Or, to give the admin access to Tenant-B we can add by following ;
Go to your Azure active directory(Contoso)> Users > Invite users .
After send the invitation in sometime there will be shown something like below the tenant we added*.
[image]

*As shown above- the invite user is already appear from their click on the invite user and add the assignments. Then from there we can give the Application Administrator access to that Tenant(Tenant-B). So the application will be accessible once we approve the request for verified account when log-in for the first time*
[image]

[image]

[image]

***For the error(Unauthorized) please make sure that you have added the **`Calendars.Readwrite`** for the users and granted admin consent as well.***

*For more information please refer the below links for the similar issues:-*

- **MS Q&A**| [***How two applications from different tenant can access each other***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/321046/how-two-applications-from-different-tenant-can-acc-1.html) .
- **SO THREAD**| [***How to access resources in one tenant from another tenant in Azure?***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68385982/how-to-access-resources-in-one-tenant-from-another-tenant-in-azure)